# Accessing a program's global variables with Intel Pin Tool

Tags: c++, intel, extern, intel-pin

I have declared an

test.cpp:

```
volatile int var;
```

and attempt to use this via extern in my pintool. However each time dlopen fails to find the variable. I have tried compiling test.cpp with -rdynamic.

Is there any way for the program and the pin tool to have some shared memory to communicate?

Comment: You want your instrumentation C functions to use the value of `var` directly?  I don't think they normally get linked together; the PIN tool just attaches to the other process like a debugger, doesn't it?  (I haven't used PIN directly, just SDE occasionally.)